# Android App to call a number on button click

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to call a number given in a textbox but I'm getting the error:

> The application 'xyz'(process com.android) has stopped unexpectedly

The following is my code.  Where is it going wrong?

```
EditText txtPhn;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button callButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCall);
    txtPhn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPhnNumber);
    callButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+txtPhn.getText().toString()));
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
                    Log.e("Calling a Phone Number", "Call failed", activityException);
                }
        }
    });
}
```

**EDITED** LogCat

```
03-09 11:23:25.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(370): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-09 11:23:25.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(370): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxx-xxx-xxxx flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.phone/.OutgoingCallBroadcaster } from ProcessRecord{40738d70 370:org.krish.android/10034} (pid=370, uid=10034) requires android.permission.CALL_PHONE
03-09 11:23:25.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(370):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
03-09 11:23:25.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(370):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
03-09 11:23:25.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(370):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1351)
03-09 11:23:25.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(370):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1374)
03-09 11:23:25.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(370):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
03-09 11:23:25.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(370):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
03-09 11:23:25.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(370):     at org.krish.android.caller$1.onClick(caller.java:29)
03-09 11:23:25.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(370):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
03-09 11:23:25.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(370):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
03-09 11:23:25.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(370):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-09 11:23:25.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(370):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-09 11:23:25.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(370):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-09 11:23:25.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(370):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-09 11:23:25.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(370):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 11:23:25.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(370):     at    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-09 11:23:25.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(370):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-09 11:23:25.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(370):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-09 11:23:25.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(370):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`enter code here`
```

Comment: have you declare <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /> permission in manifest file ?

Comment: i have add that tag in my manifest file...then also same problem

Comment: on which device you are testing and post you log output

Comment: its AVD 2.3.3 and where can i find log output ?

Comment: if you are using eclipse the use `LogCat`

Comment: Try to understand and interpret the first line of your exception. You should understand the problem.                                                 java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxx-xxx-xxxx flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.phone/.OutgoingCallBroadcaster } from ProcessRecord{40738d70 370:org.krish.android/10034} (pid=370, uid=10034) requires android.permission.CALL_PHONE

Comment: yes dude, i have added permission in my manifest file...still it is showing same error

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make sure you have added the `<uses-permission ... />` tag at a correct level in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file (*outside* the `<application ... />` tag but within the `<manifest ... />` tag):

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dbm.pkg"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <!-- NOTE! Your uses-permission must be outside the "application" tag
               but within the "manifest" tag. -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <!-- Insert your other stuff here -->

    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 11):

There are two intents to call/start calling: `ACTION_CALL` and `ACTION_DIAL`.

`ACTION_DIAL` will only open the dialer with the number filled in, but allows the user to actually call or reject the call. `ACTION_CALL` will immediately call the number and requires an extra permission.

So make sure you have the permission

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"
```

in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: yea i have added this permission `uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"` already...

Comment: then you really need to start debugging. Look at the ddms view in Eclipse - you should see the actual stacktrace. It might very well be a NullPointerException somewhere...

Comment: i have noticed a new thing, i copy pasted same thing in NetBeans and it ran perfectly...still m not getting the issue with eclipse..

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you didn't request permission from the user. If the device is running Android 6.0 (API level 23) and the app's targetSdkVersion is 23 or higher, the call permission will be considered as dangerous permission. Therefore you must get the right permission first.
First of all, add

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.android.app.myapp" >
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
      ... 
  </manifest>
```

into your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Then, I have a method is called by clicking a button.

```
public void onCall(View view) {
          Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); //use ACTION_CALL class
          callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0800000000"));    //this is the phone number calling
          //check permission
          //If the device is running Android 6.0 (API level 23) and the app's targetSdkVersion is 23 or higher,
          //the system asks the user to grant approval.
          if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
              //request permission from user if the app hasn't got the required permission
              ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                      new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},   //request specific permission from user
                      10);
              return;
          }else {     //have got permission
              try{
                  startActivity(callIntent);  //call activity and make phone call
              }
              catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"yourActivity is not founded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try the following approach:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+txtPhn.getText().toString()));
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(callIntent);
```

I.e. adding the `callIntent.setFlags(...)` function call.

Also, don't forget to add `CALL_PHONE` permission into your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 2):

API 24

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+94720999666"));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    startActivity(intent);
```

and also add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding trim():

```
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+txtPhn.getText().toString().trim()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to test it on a real device. I faced the same problem and it worked on the real device. Calling and GPS both sometimes dont work as expected in AVD.