# Cannot initiate a call from within an activity

Tags: android, android-intent, zxing

I'm building an app that should allow you to scan a QR code (or barcode) and then calls the nubmer on the barcode/QR code. I'm guessing that you cannot launch a the activity which handles the calls from within another activity because I'm getting the following error:

> No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL
>   dat=tel:xxx=xxx=xxxx }

Here is my code

```
public void scanNow(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);  
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){     

        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT"); 
                try
                { 
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(contents)); 
                startActivity(callIntent); 

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    messageBox("doStuff", e.getMessage());
                }

                // Handle successful scan
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Handle cancel
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you hold the `CALL_PHONE` permission?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android App to call a number on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230912/android-app-to-call-a-number-on-button-click)

Comment: do you have a phone on your device ?

Comment: how does SCAN_RESULT look like?

Comment: this link may help u.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005259/how-does-com-google-zxing-client-android-scan-work-in-android

Comment: @CommonsWare , yes I have hte CALL_PHONE permission.

Comment: @rusmus this is not a duplicate. The difference between my problem and the one on [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230912/android-app-to-call-a-number-on-button-click) is that in my problem, we first launch an activity(for the qr code scanner), and from within that activity we try to launch a second activity to initialte a call. in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230912/android-app-to-call-a-number-on-button-click), we try to initiate a call from a button click (only one activity is involved).

Comment: @njzk2 yes I am testing with a real physical device

Comment: @Anilkumar Actually the link doesn't really help. On this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005259/how-does-com-google-zxing-client-android-scan-work-in-android), the person uses intents to call another app installed on the phone to do the scanning. In my app, I do not call another app because I http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005259/how-does-com-google-zxing-client-android-scan-work-in-android zxing with my app

Comment: @bofredo SCAN_RESULT looks like tel:*125#

Comment: Regardless of the number of other activities you have started and ended previously, you are still attempting to start an ACTION_CALL intent from within your own app. Whether it is the result of a button click or the completion of another intent should be irrelevant. Could you post your manifest, so we can check for missing stuff?

Comment: @user1227793 : that's not my question. is your device capable of actually making calls ?